# How to call encode method of (JAVE LIBRARY) in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, nullpointerexception, illegalstateexception

I am writing a java application to convert audio file from mp3 to mp3 or other formats. I am using JAVE library. The encode method of Encoder class is a blocking method. So, I tried to run it in a separate thread. It compresses successfully but It is giving Null Pointer Exception.

Please tell me the correct way to call encode method in a new thread. How do I avoid IllegalStateException?

**run method throws NPE**

```
public class DayTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable
{

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Audio Compression Utility");

Thread myThread;

String[] bitRateValues = {"64000", "128000", "160000", "192000", "256000","320000"};
String samplingRateValues[] = {"44100", "48000","24000", "96000"};
String[] formatValues = {"wav", "mp3"};
JFileChooser sourceFileOpen = new JFileChooser();

String sourceStr = new String(), targetStr = new String() ;
 File source = null,target = null;

 Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
 EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
 AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();

 //After that i have declared JButtons , Jlabels etc..
 ...
  }
```

Class's Constructor

```
DayTwo()
{
super("Audio Compression");
setLookAndFeel();
setBounds(50,50,850,650);
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
browseTargetFileBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

Here is **run method** in constructor

```
myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Success");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
                 e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    });
```

Here is action Performed Method for "Compress"' Button

```
ActionListener actionListenerObjectForCompression =new ActionListener()
{
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          try
          {  
                audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
                audio.setBitRate( 96000 ); //96,000 = 96 kbit per sec
                audio.setSamplingRate(44100);

                attrs.setFormat("mp3");
                attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);

                myThread.start();
          }
          catch(Exception je)
          {
             je.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
};
```

Here is action Performed Method for "Browse" Button when user selects output folder

```
ActionListener actionListenerObjectForTargetLocation = new ActionListener()
{
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JFileChooser targetFileOpen = new JFileChooser();
            if (targetFileOpen.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {

                targetStr = targetFileOpen.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                browseTargetFileTextField.setText(targetStr);
                target = new File(targetStr);
            }
        }
};
```

Here is action Performed method for "Browse" button when user selects source File

```
ActionListener actionListenerObjectForSelectFile = new ActionListener()
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

    if (sourceFileOpen.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        browseTargetFileBtn.setEnabled(true);
        sourceStr = sourceFileOpen.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        browseTargetFileBtn.setEnabled(true);
        source = new  File(sourceStr);
        browseSourceFileTextField.setText(sourceFileOpen.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    }
}
};
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 DayTwo ob = new DayTwo();
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.getSelectionStart(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.PlainView.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.FieldView.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.isPopupVisible(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.getXPComboBoxState(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.paintXPComboBoxBackground(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getDisplaySize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GridLayout.minimumLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you are asking questions about code that throws exceptions and need our help, you should always post the full exception stacktrace and indicate in your code which line(s) throw the exception. Else we're flying blind.

Comment: First off, I would take care to run my Swing code on the Swing event thread, and to make sure that no Swing code is run off of this thread, other than perhaps a call to `repaint()` but little else. If still stuck, and you don't get specific help, you may need to create and post your [mcve].

Comment: My problem has solved. The exception was arising because I was accessing UI element in run method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Best solution for multi-threading issues are to use [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).
It basically divides the work to a background phase, after which occurs a GUI update stage.
A basic example:

```
   class ProperDecoder extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {
       @Override
       public Object doInBackground() {
           return decode();
       }

       @Override
       protected void done() {
           try {
               Object decoderResult = get();
               updateGUI();
           } catch (Exception ignore) {
             // catch errors
           }
       }
   }

   (new ProperDecoder()).execute();
```

Comment: These are good recommendations, 1+, but I'm not sure if it will solve the OP's NPE.